# Difference between who or whom

Tags: grammaticality

Which would be correct who or whom at the beginning of this interrogative  sentence _____ do you think will win?

Answer (score 0):

Who do you think will win?

vs.

Whom will they defeat?

The difference is simple: Who is the subject, Whom is an object.

If you were to say "I will win," or "They will defeat me" you'll see the answer right away.

Who expects an answer in the nominative case - the answer will be the subject of the sentence.

Whom expects an answer that is the object - the answer is "They will defeat whom".